# How to send push notification to firefox browser using Java

Tags: java, firefox, push-notification

Using following code I can able to send notification to Firefox.  It is working properly.

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {
                String furl = "https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/push/v1/gAAAAABXM0VF8ptA2Tl38W4b9g9Dpm0Ek2G1ZTztq0USYSYKiOicOkcB0XEewj_Oh0UnwRbia8mMxmfoWL1kyw4ix5PKFS943hYbOo-PGqpPe7qkp4GYC4wk2Mk8Yy1Yyuj6FhM_S-ec";

                HttpPut request = new HttpPut(furl); 
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request); 

                Integer responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                System.out.println(responseCode);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

But when I am trying to send title, body, and URL uanble to send to firefox. I am getting response code as 400

```
     public static void main(String args[]){
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {
    String furl = "https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/push/v1/gAAAAABXM0VF8ptA2Tl38W4b9g9Dpm0Ek2G1ZTztq0USYSYKiOicOkcB0XEewj_Oh0UnwRbia8mMxmfoWL1kyw4ix5PKFS943hYbOo-PGqpPe7qkp4GYC4wk2Mk8Yy1Yyuj6FhM_S-ec";
                JSONObject msg = new JSONObject();
                msg.put("title", "Title");
                msg.put("body", "Body");
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                json.put("data", msg); 
                HttpPut request = new HttpPut(furl); 

                request.setHeader("Content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON); 
                StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());        
                request.setEntity(params);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request); 
                Integer responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                System.out.println(responseCode);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Can any one help me on this one?

Comment: In your second code snippet, you are executing your request before your set the Header and Entity properties.

Comment: Sorry..its typo.. I am executing code after setting up the headers. I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo in your code: Content-**T**ype

```
request.setHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Comment: not sure what the issue here is.  have you tried post instead of put?

Comment: You are not setting the encoding on the StringEntity.  Can you try with encoding?  params.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));